# How to see a custom chef resource as it is executed

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have created a custom resource and obviously have an error inside.

How can i see the resource as it is executed, so that i can see where the error is. I want to run it similar as a regular recipe, where i can see all resources as t hey are executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why i couldn't see the output.

I used a non-existing variable, which seemed to confuse chef. That's why it aborted right away and did not output anything useful.